# How can we show that $|H(e^{j\omega})|=|H(e^{-j\omega})|$?

Tags: fourier-transform, linear-systems, z-transform

Let $H(z)$ be the rational system function of an LTI system.

How can we show that $|H(e^{j\omega})|=|H(e^{-j\omega})|$?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Some effort must be placed before we lend a hand!

Comment: You also need to give some context, because the way you formulated it, that equation is actually wrong. I assume you just mean "magnitude" by $||\cdot ||$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement only holds true for a real sequence $h[n]$.

The frequency response of $h[n]$ equals to

$$H(e^{j\omega}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}h[n] e^{-j\omega n}$$

and if $h(n)$ is real, the conjugate symmetry condition holds

$$H(e^{-j\omega}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}h[n] e^{j\omega n}=\big(H(e^{j\omega})\big)^*$$

So we can derive that
$$\big|H(e^{j\omega})\big| = \big|H(e^{-j\omega})\big|$$

and
$$\arg\{H(e^{j\omega})\} = -\arg\{H(e^{-j\omega})\}$$
where $\arg\{\cdot\}$ represents phase response.

We can also derive that the real part of the frequency response is even symmetric and the imaginary part is odd symmetric.
$$\Re\{H(e^{j\omega})\} = \big|H(e^{j\omega})\big| \cos\big(\arg\{H(e^{j\omega})\}\big) = \Re\{H(e^{-j\omega})\}$$
$$\Im\{H(e^{j\omega})\} = \big|H(e^{j\omega})\big| \sin\big(\arg\{H(e^{j\omega})\}\big) = -\Im\{H(e^{-j\omega})\}$$

Answer (score 2):

A simple counter-example: take a causal two tap FIR filter $H(z)=h[0]+h[1]z^{-1}$ with $h[1]\neq 0$. Now we have $H(z^{-1})=h[0]+h[1]z$. Take any $z\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $|z|\neq 1$ and verify that $|H(z)|\neq |H(z^{-1})|$.

So try to figure out what it is that is actually meant. Could it be that you mean that equality holds for $|z|=1$, i.e., on the unit circle?

---

Now that the question has been edited, we just have to prove the given equality for $|z|=1$. Note that we need yet another requirement, namely that the system is real-valued, i.e., its impulse response $h[n]$ is real. In that case the frequency response is conjugate symmetrical:

$$H(e^{j\omega})=H^*(e^{-j\omega})\tag{1}$$

and, consequently,

$$|H(e^{j\omega})|=|H^*(e^{-j\omega})|=|H(e^{-j\omega})|\tag{2}$$

must hold.

Comment: @ Matt L.  you are right. I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Even after your edit, we can't show what is wrong.

Counterexample:

$$h(\tau)=\delta(\tau)+\frac j{\pi\tau}$$

Convolution with that is an LTI system.

That system happens to be the Hilbert transformator.

Comment: only the imaginary part (which is the stuff that multiplies $j$ in the right-hand term) $\frac{1}{\pi \tau}$ is the impulse response of a Hilbert Transformer.